# Make permanent changes to iptables rules

Tags: iptables

I am trying to add some custom rules for the `INPUT` iptables chain in a permanent way.

Since my host is running docker, the number of chains as well as the rules in these chains can change on the fly, depending on the docker configuration.

Some research lead me to `iptables-save` and `iptables-restore` command, which basically dump all chains to stdout. This lead several times to a broken system already:

1. Manually dump config via `iptables-save` to a file
2. Docker daemon changed some iptables rules
3. System got rebooted, restoring the rules saved in step 1.)
4. Result: Inconsistent rules since the latest docker changes have been overwritten

How to make custom iptables rules permanent, avoiding the all-or-nothing scenario?

Comment: You might be able to use your current implementation if you make sure to remove the Docker specific rules resulting from step 1 and apply your `iptables` rules before Docker attempts to start on reboot.  If that does not work, I would suggest either separating the Docker rules from your permanent rules or writing your own Docker `iptables` rules and not allowing Docker to do it dynamically anymore.

Answer (score 2):

**Red Hat / CentOS:**

```
# Stop and disable firewalld
systemctl stop firewalld
systemctl disable firewalld
yum clean all
# Install and start iptables
yum install iptables-services -y
systemctl enable iptables
systemctl start iptables
# Save the rules
service iptables save
```

**Debian / Ubuntu:**

```
# Install iptables
apt-get update
apt install  iptables-persistent -y
# Save the rules
netfilter-persistent save
netfilter-persistent reload
```