# Can't ping external sites in Linux guest that already has internet access

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, firewall

I have an Ubuntu 20.10 guest and an Ubuntu 20.04 host and other devices on my LOCAL network, but for some reason the guest can't ping websites (e.g. `ping google.com`). What's interesting is that I have a fully functional internet connection on the Guest (I've watched YouTube through the guest's Firefox). Additionally, I can successfully ping any website on the Ubuntu 20.04 host.

Here's the output of ping on the guest: (same command that works on the host)

```shellsession
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

and it hangs... until I press ctrl + c:

```
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
61 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 61426ms
```

This shouldn't even be a DNS problem since I'm pinging an IP.

Here's my guest network configuration:

- Bridged adapter
- Intel PRO/1000 MT Desktop
- Promiscuous Mode: Allow All
- Cable Connected

I'm running Virtualbox 6.1., but I faced the same issue with VMWare Player.

The same issue was present when I tried Arch Linux's installation medium as the guest.

Here are some solutions I've tried already that haven't worked:

- I followed [this](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-iptables-how-to-flush-all-rules.html) tutorial to clear all rules from both the host and guest and made them permanent using instructions on [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/583153/make-permanent-changes-to-iptables-rules) page. Same result.
- In Virtualbox I tried setting the adapter to NAT and changing Promiscuous mode; again, same result.

### Edit: some additional info

Guest IP: `192.168.12.77`

```
2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:b2:c6:c1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.12.77/24 brd 192.168.12.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute
```

Host IP: `192.168.12.150`

```
2: wlp0s20f3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 64:bc:58:11:50:5d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.12.150/24 brd 192.168.12.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp0s20f3
       valid_lft 84558sec preferred_lft 84558sec
    inet6 fd51:f3be:f061:0:bf48:13a5:5d92:a1e8/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 602960sec preferred_lft 84267sec
    inet6 fd51:f3be:f061:0:d99b:e3e7:53f9:30e8/64 scope global mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 2607:fb90:cb17:4431:f871:b774:d991:1f43/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 602960sec preferred_lft 84267sec
    inet6 2607:fb90:cb17:4431:c45c:624c:7bb0:db35/64 scope global mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::bc99:7476:5b8d:295b/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Guest to host ping works:

```shellsession
~$ ping 192.168.12.150
PING 192.168.12.150 (192.168.12.150) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.12.150: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.268 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.12.150: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.199 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.12.150: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.208 ms
```

Host to guest ping works:

```shellsession
~$ ping 192.168.12.77
PING 192.168.12.77 (192.168.12.77) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.12.77: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.391 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.12.77: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.216 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.12.77: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.214 ms
```

Comment: Please update your post with the Guest's IP address, and the Host's IP address.

Comment: @eyoung100 done!

Comment: Is there a DNS server in your Router?  i.e.., does pinging your default gateway from the Guest succeed?  If you can ping the default gateway, open that in a browser, and check the connection settings.  Your ISP should be leasing you a routable IP plus their company DNS Server

Comment: Can you pint the gateway from the guest? Is the (default-)gateway on the host the same as the gateway on the guest (`netstat -rn` on both)?

Comment: Is there a route configured?

Comment: Default route on the host and guest is the same? (`netstat -rn` or `ip route` - either command is fine but use the same command on both systems please)

Comment: The host and guest addresses are in the same IP LAN. That usually means bridging. Now, bridging on a system being a Wifi client (rather than AP) doesn't work. There are workarounds like Linux' IPVLAN or what virtualbox implements for Wifi to keep a single MAC address in use, but these are fragile, and it appears they don't work here. So you really should describe your topology and avoid bridging when not using actual wired Ethernet. At the same time I can see no bridge, but at the very least proxy ARP would be needed to route the same IP LAN. Don't use the same IP LAN on the guest for routing.